# Give input in the child process after spawn in node

Tags: node.js, child-process

i am working on a small web app and came across this difficulity !
i have a `.py` file named main.py

the node-js code is -

```js
const python = spawn('python', ['main.py', req.body.id, req.body.hash, req.body.bot_token]);
python.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
    if (data.toString().endsWith('=')) {
        console.log(data.toString());
    } else {
        console.log('error')
    }
});
```

Now The Python File Needs Some **Inputs As A Verification Code..**
How Do Give The Inputs And Then Capture The Data ?

I want To Give The Input Automatically
Let Say code recieved and the user gave the code on website in a input tag..

Now i want this `input.value` To give as The Input Without Human Effort..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: `python.stdin.write()`?

Comment: i tried that but it just prints the input message,
and stops.

i need it to give the input and enter it..

Comment: Did you also write the linebreak to "finish" the input?

Comment: yes take the python code as `a = input('Some Input : ') print(a + 'abc')`, 

let i did this `python.stdin.write('data\n')` and it printed 'data' from js not python